# Multiple url with same content in umbraco as follows

Tags: url-rewriting, duplicates, content-management-system, umbraco

[image][image][image][image]https://www.6storage.com/aboutus/  ----- It is an URL
https://www.6storage.com/features/   ----- It is an URL

if I search as https://www.6storage.com/aboutus/features/  it is going to feature page content.

Can someone help me with it

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of how your content tree looks? Also, the features page now redirects, so can you confirm that this question is still relevant?

Comment: added screenshots.Please look into it

Comment: @Mike B please check the above

Comment: I meant the content tree within Umbraco, so I can confirm that you have a "contactus" node, with a "features" node underneath it.

Comment: @Mike B added content tree

Comment: It's probably best to try this on a separate environment, but try right-clicking the root node and publishing every node underneath it (i.e. the whole content tree). If you're still getting the issue, maybe try deleting the umbraco.config file from App_Data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use URl rewrite module (simple301)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).